# Google Colaboratory: os.mkdir: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, mkdir

I am trying to run [03_01_autoencoder_train.ipynb](https://github.com/davidADSP/GDL_code/blob/master/03_01_autoencoder_train.ipynb) on Google Colaboratory.  However, I am getting this error:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-7a5d04d83c0d> in <module>()
      7 
      8 if not os.path.exists(RUN_FOLDER):
----> 9     os.mkdir(RUN_FOLDER)
     10     os.mkdir(os.path.join(RUN_FOLDER, 'viz'))
     11     os.mkdir(os.path.join(RUN_FOLDER, 'images'))

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'run/vae/0001_digits'
```

What is going wrong here.  [Here is a link to my file](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1tm9cVcXlFy9iTVm3A9s5FliGih97J83u?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

Google Colab does not have acess to does folders. It is searching in its self contained environment. To get this code running simply add the folders you need in colab.
For example:
[image: Like this]

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to make it work. Just replace `mkdir` method under `if`-code on `makedirs`:

```
if not os.path.exists(RUN_FOLDER):
    os.makedirs(RUN_FOLDER)
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(RUN_FOLDER, 'viz'))
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(RUN_FOLDER, 'images'))
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(RUN_FOLDER, 'weights'))
```